# Firebase Phone Auth Verification is very slow

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, presentviewcontroller

Im using Firebase phone authentication to verify a users phone number and log them in after creating an account. I would like to perform a segue to the next screen to enter the code that Firebase auth sends to the phone after the reCaptcha completes. The reCaptcha screen seems to load very slowly taking almost 10 full seconds to appear. Is there any way to speed this up am I doing anything wrong. Below is the code which handles this process.

```
PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("An error has occured while trying to authenticate phone number: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(verificationID, forKey: "authVerificationID")
    // Sign in using the verificationID and the code sent to the user
    // ...
    verifyViewController.verificationID = verificationID
    print("Verification id created")

                    let transition = CATransition()
                    transition.duration = 0.03
                    transition.type = CATransitionType.push
                    transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromRight
                    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
                    self.view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)

                    self.present(verifyViewController, animated: false, completion: {
                        print("presented Verify View Controller")
                    })

}
```

Comment: Any solutions . Facing the same issue.

Comment: @adiinstack No the best I could do was disable push notifications and that seemed to speed it up a bit.

Comment: Did you try preconnect ?

Comment: Facing the same issue. After calling verifyPhoneNumber it goes way too much to get any feedback from the API. This happens only on iOS.